# Do I need to embargo my dissertation if I submitted portions to journals?

Tags: journals, research-dissemination

It seems that most math journals, including the one I'm submitting to, are very forgiving when it comes to preprints (ArXiv).  But what about dissertations? Will they consider it previously published material?

Comment: In maths? Pretty surely not. (To precise "pretty surely" somewhat: Journals who would dismiss papers published in a dissertation will quickly lose their reputation once this behavior gets known.) Note that I am talking about mathematics journals here.

Comment: Up until just a few years ago, the vast majority of first papers of mathematicians were based on their thesis work.  With this culture in mind, the idea of a thesis as a "prior publication" seems bonkers.  (Note that in many other STEM fields the order is reversed: you know you have a thesis when you have published enough papers.)  Maybe you can find a math journal somewhere that has a problem with this...but maybe you can't.  For sure it is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Most journals clearly state what is allowed for authors and what is not. Could you provide the name of the journal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general answer is: No, journals don't consider dissertations as previously published materials.

Some exceptions (that I don't know), may exist. If you want to be sure, here's a two things you can do:
1-Verify the instructions to authors.
2-In your letter to the editor that accompanies your submission, state clearly that this manuscript will be part of a dissertation.